# Not able to share symlinked folders with Dropbox for Mac?

Tags: finder, dropbox, symlink

I'm having a problem with the Dropbox client for the Mac. I have symlinked `~/Projects/` into `~/Dropbox/Projects/` using MacDropAny.app, which basically runs `ln -s`. This works as suspected. But when I try to right click a file or folder within my `Dropbox/Projects` folder, the Dropbox sharing alternatives are not showing. These items appears fine in other, none-symlinked folders inside Dropbox.

If I go through Dropbox.com, i can share this folder/subfolders fine. But I want to be able to easily share linkes to files/folders from the Mac right click context menu. Any tips/ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Another thing, that might be related, is that you don't get the green/blue sync status icon on subfolders when using symlinks.

Comment: If this turns out to be a bug, you might want to add this to the drawbacks of using symlinks with Dropbox - http://superuser.com/questions/383475/using-only-the-dropbox-folders-vs-symlinks-on-os-x

Comment: What if you create the symlink manually and not use the app?

Comment: @Allan Tried to set symlink manually. Same problem, only one difference. A "Move to Dropbox" option appeard, which doesn't show in the other symlinked folder. 